# What are the permissions needed to access blob from Kusto Python SDK?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-explorer, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to ingest an append blob in ADLS gen 2 to ADX with the Python SDK.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
blob_descriptor = BlobDescriptor(
    "https://<STORAGEACC>.dfs.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER>/<BLOB>.gz"
)
res=client.ingest_from_blob(blob_descriptor, ingestion_properties=ingestion_props)
```

When i run `.show ingestion failures`, here is my output:
[image]
[image]

What permissions are required to access the blob? And are the permissions to be granted at the blob level to my Azure Data Explorer cluster or to the client running the python script?
(Also, I have given the ADX Cluster 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' permissions and also to myself (since the client is currently being tested with with_aad_device_authentication() )

Answer (score 1):

as can be seen in the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-python/blob/master/azure-kusto-ingest/tests/sample.py), the URL to the blob should include storage credentials (for example, a [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview)).

See: [Storage connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/storage-connection-strings)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the docs suggest that Managed Identity, Azure AD are also supported authentication formats and that the credentials are optional. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/storage-connection-strings

Comment: I think you meant "specifying the authentication type, if credentials aren't required, is mandatory", and not "credentials are optional"

Comment: oh okay. understood. since i am trying in my dev setup. i tried impersonate. But i do not see any ingestion success or failure metric

Comment: Impersonation is not supported with Queued Ingestion.